# laravel 5 update multiple columns in one line?

Tags: laravel-5.4

It's possible update multiple columns in one line with laravel 5.4?

I try to this

```
        DB::table('Home_Content')->where('id',1)->update(
        [$_POST['name'] => $_POST['content']],
        [$_POST['title'] => $_POST['titleMsg']]
        );
```

only 1st part is work([$_POST['name'] => $_POST['content']])

server not return any error, but only 1st part is success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update method syntax in `Laravel` is like so :

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->update(['options->enabled' => true]);
```

Which means the values we want to update are inside an array, what I've seen is that you separated what you want to update into two arrays

```
DB::table('Home_Content')->where('id',1)->update(
    [$_POST['name'] => $_POST['content']],
    [$_POST['title'] => $_POST['titleMsg']]
    );
```

so now you are out of the array

Your code should be like this

```
DB::table('Home_Content')->where('id',1)->update([
    $_POST['name'] => $_POST['content'],
    $_POST['title'] => $_POST['titleMsg']
]);
```

Meaning each pair has a key and a value and separated with `comma`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update record in multiple row with id as Array() use following query.

```
DB::table('users')
    ->whereIn('id', [1,2,3])
    ->update(['status' => 1]);
```